# emacs regexp-builder doesn't work in replace-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

I have an emacs buffer containing the text

```
a1b2c3
```

using the regexp-builder, i create the regexp

```
"b\\(2\\)"
```

and can see the match highlighting (b2, with the 2 in a different colour).

however, when i paste the expression into `replace-regexp`, i get 0 matches. both with and without the quotes. to get a match i need to use

```
b\(2\)
```

i guess there's some escaping going on here, but surely i must be doing something wrong. having to manually escape seems to defeat half the point.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`regexp-builder` can show the regexp in several syntaxes. By default, it uses the syntax that is appropriate to put in an Emacs Lisp source (`read` syntax), so the regexp is placed between double quotes and every backslash is doubled. For interactive use, select the `string` syntax with `C-c C-i` (`reb-change-syntax`).

Comment: I'm really confused by this answer ; Consider this:

`string[5string]'

now regexp-builder matches the "5" ("any number preceded by an opening angle bracket") with "\\[[0-9]". Now if I `M-x query-replace \\[[0-9] RET plop' I get nothing. I tried \\[\[0-9\] (works in builder too), nothing.

You did not indicate where I'm supposed to type `C-c C-i' : in the regexp-builder, in the minibuffer while using it, elsewhere? Turned out it was in the regexp-builder, but then it offers me 4 choices (read, rx, sregex, string) which one should I choose **so that emacs understands it's own regexp syntax?**

Comment: Wow the comment syntax escapes the escape chars, that will make commenting about the escape chars uneasy :) Seriously, even in "code" markers, escaping?

Comment: @PhilippeCM I'm a bit confused by your comment, and it's not just because of the missing backslashes. If you're typing a regexp interactively, pick `string`. If you mean to insert the regexp in a Lisp snippet, pick `read`, which writes a Lisp string literal with `\\ ` and `"` escaped.

Comment: At least in Emacs 24.2, picking `string` doesn't change what gets copied by `C-c C-w`. You need manually select the expression between quotes to get a version usable in `replace-regexp`.

Comment: I'm looking for functionality for the work flow of starting with regexp-builder, build the desired regular expression interactively, (trial-and-error), after reached the desired one, issue a command to reuse the built regex expression to do replace-regex in emacs. Please share if it's already possible? or Some alternative? Thanks,

Comment: @YuShen Sounds like a question you could ask on [emacs.se].

Comment: @YuShen did you happen to ever find or implement that workflow? if not I may try to.

Comment: @scry No, I haven't done it. It would be super, if you could. Thanks in advance!

Comment: My workflow for a default emacs 26.1 install: Run `re-builder` via `M-x re-builder`. Build regular expression within the double quotes (`"  "`) provided; escaped characters like parentheses and curly braces require double backslashes. Once the expression is working in `re-builder` and you want to run it in `query-replace-regexp`, first copy ONLY the text within the double quotes; then, paste it into a throwaway buffer so you can replace the double backslashes with single backslashes; now, paste the result into `query-replace-regexp` (`C-M-s` or `M-x query-replace-regexp`).