# Regexp languages and replacements in Emacs

Tags: regex, emacs, pcre

When I use the `regexp-builder`, I need to escape things in a different way from the way I do it when using `replace-regexp`. Now, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516222/emacs-regexp-builder-doesnt-work-in-replace-regexp?rq=1) explains that these two commands use a different syntax, but why is that?

Also, I went through this blog post: [Re-builder: The Interactive Regexp Builder](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/04/12/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder/), and I added

```
(require 're-builder) 
(setq reb-re-syntax 'string)
```

to my `.emacs` file following the advice on the site. However, I still need to type `"` around my regexp to make it work. I thought changing the syntax language would take care of this but it doesn't.

With this, my actual questions are:

1. Is it sill the case that Emacs does not support [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE)? Are there any workarounds to this?
2. Once I have the right regexp in `regex-builder`, is there any way to **directly** send the regexp to `replace-regexp` and enter the replacement string?

Comment: @devnull Thanks! I just fixed that.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118183/elisp-mechanism-for-converting-pcre-regexps-to-emacs-regexps) might interest you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a package in the MELPA repository called [pcre2el](https://github.com/joddie/pcre2el) that adds PCRE support to many parts of Emacs, including `regexp-builder` and `replace-regexp`.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding question #2: No (at least not by default), but there's another way to do that without using re-builder.

- Start by doing a regexp isearch for your pattern. Because it's an isearch, you'll see the matches interactively, a bit like re-builder (albeit without coloured groupings).
- Still in isearch, once you're happy with the pattern, type <kbd>C-M-%</kbd> to call `isearch-query-replace-regexp` which will prompt you for the replacement.

You can of course simply copy your re-builder string from its buffer and yank it as a replacement string (but that's undoubtedly not news).

I was curious about the need for quotes in re-builder with string syntax. It seems that's it's just a formality of the system, and `reb-read-regexp` returns everything between the first and last `"` when using that syntax. Maybe it's intended to ensure that leading or trailing whitespace can't confuse matters -- re-builder does use leading whitespace for improved visibility, and trailing whitespace would be harder to spot. Or maybe it just made some of the code more convenient/consistent.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, Emacs doesn't support PCRE, and as far as I know there is no work-around for that.
2. I don't think so.

To answer your first question, why does re-builder use a different syntax than replace-regexp:

By default, `re-builder` uses the syntax that is appropriate for writing elisp programs. In the context of a written program, regexps are entered within strings. Inside a string, backslashes have a special meaning which conflicts with using the backslash as part of a regexp. Consequently, within a string, you need to *double* a backslash to use it to signify part of the regexp syntax.

`replace-regexp`, on the other hand, is designed to be used interactively by the user, and it explicitly expects the input to be a regexp. As a convenience, it interprets backslashes as regexp syntax, not as string escapes. Which is why you can use single backslashes in this context.

Comment: +1. The key is the difference between Lisp syntax and interactive syntax.